# Android App crashes on Button click

Tags: android

I have made a simple application which takes two numbers and add them but on button click my app crashes every time. I am new to android, Id really appreciate if someone can help me with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ornadmin.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="number 1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="number 2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick (MainActivity)"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.ornadmin.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        int sum = num1 + num2;
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**LOG**

```
 --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ornadmin.myapplication, PID: 3812
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onButtonClick (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button'
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4479)
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4443)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick (MainActivity)"
```

the correction would be like this

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```